# How to calculate median in mysql by using case when

Tags: mysql, median, case-when

I have a table named `station` having a column `LAT_N`. I am trying to get the median of `LAT_N`.

So here is my query:

```
select 
case when count(Lat_N)%2=0 then (select (Lat_N from station limit (1,ceil(count(Lat_N)/2))+ select (Lat_N from station limit (1,floor(count(Lat_N)/2)))))
else (Select Lat_N from station limit(1,floor(count(Lat_N)/2)+1))
end
from station;
```

Comment: update your question add  a proper data sample and the expected  result  ..

Comment: What version are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Try following query:

```
SELECT avg(tmp1.LAT_N) as median_LAT FROM (
SELECT @rownum:=@rownum+1 as row_number, s.val
  FROM station s,  (SELECT @rownum:=0) r
  ORDER BY s.LAT_N
) as tmp1, 
(
  SELECT count(*) as total_rows
  FROM station s
) as tmp2
AND tmp1.row_number in ( floor((total_rows+1)/2), floor((total_rows+2)/2) );
```